# Trying to update the poll count after each vote

Tags: javascript, html

I have a poll for my mock website where I need to vote for one of three contestants. I need to store the vote in local storage and then after each additional vote, I need to update the vote in local storage and display it beside the contestants. My main problem is with updating the vote in local storage. I have to do it with only javaScript, HTML and CSS

```
<html>
<body>
<fieldset>

    <legend> <h3>Vote For Your Favorite Chef! </h3></legend>

    <form onsubmit="getChoice()" id="pollForm"> <!-- do js for the getCHoice-->

        <input type="radio" id="Nominee1" name="Nominee" value="Reynold Poernomo"  required/>
        <label for="Nominee1"> Reynold Poernomo </label>
        <span id="nom1" class="vote"></span>

        <br/>
        <input type="radio" id="Nominee1.1" name="Nominee" value="Christine Tania" required>
        <label for="Nominee1.1"> Christine Tania </label>
        <span id="nom2" class="vote"></span>

        <br/>
        <input type="radio" id="Nominee1.2" name="Nominee" value="Christina Tosi" required>
        <label for="Nominee1.2"> Christina Tosi </label>
        <span id="nom3" class="vote"></span> <br />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <script src="js/localStorage.js"></script>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>

<script>

function incrementPoll() {
    let nominee1 = document.getElementById('Nominee1').value;
    let nominee2 = document.getElementById('Nominee2').value;
    let nominee3 = document.getElementById('Nominee3').value;

    if (nominee1.checked == true) {
        updatePoll("Nominee1");
    } else if (nominee2.checked == true) {
        updatePoll("Nominee2");
    } else if (nominee3.checked == true) {
        updatePoll("Nominee3");
    }
}

function updatePoll(entry) {
    let voteUpdate = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(entry),10) + 1;

   return  localStorage.setItem(entry, (Number(voteUpdate)).toString()); //how to convert to string


}
```

These two functions are supposed to check which button is being selected and updates the vote in local storage. But it doesn't actually work.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the count to string?

Comment: In `incrementPoll` you're selecting the `value` of the checkboxes, which are strings. They don't have the `checked` property, so none of your `if` statements will fire. It should be `let nominee1 = document.getElementById('Nominee1')`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of your code. I hope this helps.

```js
const nominee1 = document.getElementById('Nominee1');
const nominee2 = document.getElementById('Nominee2');
const nominee3 = document.getElementById('Nominee3');

function incrementPoll(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (nominee1.checked == true) {
    updatePoll("Nominee1");
  } else if (nominee2.checked == true) {
    updatePoll("Nominee2");
  } else if (nominee3.checked == true) {
    updatePoll("Nominee3");
  }
}

function updatePoll(entry) {
  const voteUpdate = (parseInt(localStorage.getItem(entry), 10) || 0) + 1;
  localStorage.setItem(entry, voteUpdate);
  document.querySelector(`#${entry.replace('Nominee', 'nom')}`).innerText = voteUpdate;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <h3>Vote For Your Favorite Chef! </h3>
  </legend>

  <form onsubmit="incrementPoll(event)" id="pollForm">
    <input type="radio" id="Nominee1" name="Nominee" value="Reynold Poernomo" required/>
    <label for="Nominee1"> Reynold Poernomo </label>
    <span id="nom1" class="vote"></span>

    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="Nominee2" name="Nominee" value="Christine Tania" required>
    <label for="Nominee1.1"> Christine Tania </label>
    <span id="nom2" class="vote"></span>

    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="Nominee3" name="Nominee" value="Christina Tosi" required>
    <label for="Nominee2"> Christina Tosi </label>
    <span id="nom3" class="vote"></span> <br />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

Since the snippet won't work because `localStorage` is not accessible in an SO snippet, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uea9Losv/1/)

Comment: what does this line do in the incrementPoll() function? "e.preventDefault();"

Comment: Please refrain from using inline event handlers, [here's why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these). Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: @LabinaTasfia when you add an event listener to an element you get some information about the event that has been fired. That information is in the form of an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object. That object also has the power to stop the browser from doing what it should do when an event happens, in this case that is submitting the form and reloading the browser window. This is done by calling the [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method on the `Event` object.